# database structure for multiple options on products

Tags: mysql, database

I have products in my database (MySQL).
I have my prices based on different combinations of options for my products.
I have the following data:

**PRODUCTS**

```
prodID | prodName
1      | Ball
```

**OPTIONS**

```
optionID | optionName | prodID
1        | color      | 1
2        | size       | 1
3        | material   | 1
```

**OPTIONVALUES**

```
ovID | optionID | ovValue
1    | 1        | red
2    | 1        | blue
3    | 2        | small
4    | 2        | big
5    | 3        | wood
6    | 3        | glass
```

for prices I would like to have like this:

red small wood ball - $13
red small glass ball - 14
red big wood ball - 16
red big glass ball - 17
blue small wood ball - 12.5
[...]

How can I design the database structure for this?
I have tried several ways but none was good. if the number of the options were static then every option could have its own table, but this was that is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like what you already have. If you want it to be fully flexible as i guess you do, i would do the following:

Add two more Tables.

Product_Instance

```
instanceID | prodID | price
1          | 1      | 13
```

Product_Instance_Options

```
instanceID | ovID
1          | 1
1          | 3
1          | 6
```

In this way you could define all possible combinations and prices for them. Might be a hell of a lot work to set up all the prices, but if you cant calculate them (like glass = +2$, small=2$ / big=4$) you will have this however you do it.

Comment: how would you query this to get a price for a given array of options?

Comment: answer to my comment question above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296781/mysql-select-from-tables-based-on-multiple-rows

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

**productTypes**

```
prodID | prodName
1      | Ball
2      | Car
```

**productInstances**

```
prodInstanceID | prodID | Prize
1              | 1      | $19
2              | 1      | $50
3              | 2      | $8
```

**properties**

```
propertyID  | propertyName
1           | color
2           | size
3           | material
```

**propertiesValues**

```
pvID |propertyID  | propertyName
1    | 1          | red
2    | 1          | blue
3    | 2          | small
4    | 2          | medium
5    | 2          | large
6    | 3          | wood
7    | 3          | glass
```

**productProperties**

```
ppID | prodInstanceID | pvID
1    | 1              | 1
2    | 1              | 3
3    | 1              | 6
4    | 2              | 2
5    | 2              | 4
6    | 2              | 7
7    | 3              | 1
8    | 3              | 3 
9    | 3              | 6
```

In your design you can't determine which option belongs to which product instance. If you look at your table optionvalues, there is no way to group together your options.

Comment: you have to insert all the values (like red/small) for each and every instance of every product. You might find the word "small" hundreds or thousands of times in your Database. This is redundant = bad.

Comment: anyway, +1 for a closely appropiation

Comment: @Flo, you are right about that. I modified my answer. Moved price to productinstance and created a propertyvalues table.

Edit: Actually, now my answer is the same as your answer.

Comment: jea and now youre answer is pretty much the same as mine only with an additional primary key. (which is not neccesary)