# MYSQL Select from tables based on multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called `user_meta`. In that table I have the following columns: `ID`, `userID`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`

I have another table called `users`, the only important column there is `ID`, which I want to compare to the `user_meta` table rows.

The `users` table looks like:

```
ID    |    email   | etc...
1     |    email@test.com  |
5     |    testa@a.com   |
6     |    ....   |
7     |    ....   |
```

So say I have a table (user_meta) that looks like:

```
ID   |   userID   |   meta_key  |   meta_value
2    |   1        |   companyID |   2
3    |   1        |   user_type |   staff
4    |   5        |   companyID |   2
5    |   5        |   user_type |   staff
6    |   6        |   companyID |   4
7    |   6        |   user_type |   customer
```

I want to retrieve a single row for each `userID`, but only if the company ID and user_type are correct.

I want to retrieve all users that have the same companyID that I would send in the query, so let's say $companyID=2, and then all users that have the `user_type`='staff'.

So user_meta.userID must equal users.ID, and user_meta.companyID must equal 2, and user_meta.user_type must equal 'staff'.

I want a list of all users that match these criteria.

A result would be `userID` 1 & 5 are returned. They both have `companyID = 2`, and both have `user_type = staff`

Comment: provide the table structure of both this tables and also the desired result came from your example datas

Comment: @NewbeeDev I added the users table, the only important column is ID. users.ID = user_meta.userID

Comment: perhaps a result your desired query would help us understand your problem more.

Comment: @NewbeeDev added an expected result at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join with `user_meta` once for each attribute you want to match.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users AS u
JOIN user_meta AS m1 ON u.id = m1.userID
JOIN user_meta AS m2 ON u.id = m2.userID
WHERE m1.meta_key = 'companyID' AND m1.meta_value = :companyID
AND m2.meta_key = 'user_type' AND m2.meta_value = 'staff'
```

Comment: This seems to be working how I wanted.. I will finish coding to make sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, 
       `Company`.`meta_value`, 
       `UserType`.`meta_value` 
FROM   `users` 
       JOIN `user_meta` `Company` 
         ON `Company`.`userid` = `users`.`id` 
       JOIN `user_meta` `UserType` 
         ON `UserType`.`userid` = `users`.`id` 
WHERE  `UserType`.`meta_value` = 'staff' 
       AND `Company`.`meta_value` = 2
```

https://gyazo.com/de8d9124418f65b993d708c80c309325

Answer (score -1):

Not very sure about your question. I'm assuming this is what you may want:

```
select * from Users where ID in (
select userID from user_meta where (meta_key = 'companyID' and meta_value = 2) or (meta_key = 'user_type' and meta_value = 'staff')
);
```

Comment: This will get everyone who is either in company 2 or is staff, it doesn't require them to be both.

Comment: @Barmar Ah yes you are right. I didn't get the question right

Comment: @PremRaj yes thank you for your attempt, I know the question is a bit confusing.

Comment: It's actually a pretty common request, and wrong answers like this are also common.