# SELECT with SELECT within IF statement with saving state

Tags: mysql

I try to found some solution to avoid third SELECT, but I don't even know, how google it.

My try (working, but looks ugly):

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    IF(
        (SELECT meta_value from usermeta WHERE user_id = u.ID AND meta_key = 'first_name') = '',
        'John',
        (SELECT meta_value from usermeta WHERE user_id = u.ID AND meta_key = 'first_name')
    ) as first_name,
    (SELECT meta_value from usermeta WHERE user_id = u.ID AND meta_key = 'reputation') as reputation
FROM wp_users AS u
```

And I'd like something like this:

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    IF(
        (SELECT meta_value from usermeta WHERE user_id = u.ID AND meta_key = 'first_name') = '',
        'John',
        SOME_STATE0
    ) as first_name,
    (SELECT meta_value from usermeta WHERE user_id = u.ID AND meta_key = 'reputation') as reputation
FROM wp_users AS u
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables rather than using a subquery.

```
SELECT u.*, IF(meta_value = '' OR meta_value IS NULL, 'John', meta_value) AS first_name
FROM wp_users AS u
LEFT JOIN usermeta AS m ON m.user_id = u.id AND m.meta_key = 'first_name'
```

Comment: Can't, because I need few values from that table. Second table contains key-values for user entity, and I need for one user to get a few rows from that as additional columns.

Comment: For instance, from every user I need to add columns with rows values: user + usermeta value, where key is 'first_name' + usermeta value, where key is 'last_name' + etc

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296781/mysql-select-from-tables-based-on-multiple-rows/40297059?noredirect=1#comment67852325_40297059 for how to pick up multiple attributes from an attribute-value table like `usermeta`.

Comment: It's genially! Thanks!