# Limiting SQL LIKE to same wildcard in AND parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I'm trying to create a SQL query that retrieves records based on the start and end dates. However, the system doesn't have a very nice Database schema, so I'm looking for a way to create a query that works with it.

Basically, there's a meta table that stores the events' dates using the "date_NUMBER_(start|end)" format:

| event_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | date_0_start | 2022-04-02 |
| 1 | date_0_end | 2022-04-03 |
| - | - | - |
| 2 | date_0_start | 2022-03-21 |
| 2 | date_0_end | 2022-03-22 |
| 2 | date_1_start | 2022-06-24 |
| 2 | date_1_end | 2022-06-30 |

So, Event 1 has one date span: **2022-04-02** to **2022-04-03**. While Event 2 has two: **2022-03-21** to **2022-03-22** and **2022-06-24** to **2022-06-30**.

After **2022-03-22**, Event 2 is not active, starting again only on **2022-06-24**.

To create a filter that works with this schema, I came up with the following SQL query. For example, to search for events happening between the **2022-04-01** - **2022-04-03** range (any event that there's an event day between the range):

```
SELECT events.id
FROM events INNER JOIN events_meta ON ( events.id = events_meta.event_id ) INNER JOIN events_meta AS evt1 ON (
events.id = evt1.event_id )
WHERE 

(
( 
    events_meta.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start' AND
    CAST(events_meta.meta_value AS DATE) >= '2022-04-01'
)
AND
(
    evt1.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end' AND
    CAST(evt1.meta_value AS DATE) <= '2022-04-03'
)

)
```

The problem is that in this way, I should get only Event 1, but Event 2 is also returned since date_1_start is >= '2022-04-01' and date_0_end is <= '2022-04-03'

I'm not being able to find a way where I can match the NUMBER in the "date_NUMBER_(start|end)" meta_key format, so the query doesn't compare different NUMBERs.

Any help is appreciated :)

---

I made a fiddle with the INNER JOIN query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb497e/2

Comment: I suggest self-join and then filtering.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the WHERE in the question

Comment: Your `WHERE` condition can never be true. `meta_key` can't be like `date_%_start` and `date_%_end` in the same row.

Comment: You have to match date_n_start with date_n_end.

Comment: I tried to simplify the query and it went wrong, so I made a sqlfiddle with the actual one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb497e/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a self-join to get different keys for the same event ID. See [MYSQL Select from tables based on multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296781/mysql-select-from-tables-based-on-multiple-rows/40297059)

```
SELECT m1.event_id, m1.meta_value AS start, m2.meta_value AS end
FROM events_meta AS m1
JOIN events_meta AS m2 
    ON m1.event_id = m2.event_id 
        AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(m1.meta_key, '_', 2) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(m2.meta_key, '_', 2)
WHERE m1.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start' AND m2.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end'
    AND CAST(m1.meta_value AS DATE) >= '2022-04-01'
    AND CAST(m2.meta_value AS DATE) <= '2022-04-03'
```

The `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` calls will return the prefixes `date_0`, `date_1`, etc. Including this in the `ON` condition will pair up the corresponding start and end keys.

Comment: Awesome! Just a question: adding the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` condition as another AND at the end of the query also works. Is there any difference from how you made it? Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb497e/7

Comment: There's generally no difference between putting these conditions in `ON` or `WHERE` (left join is an exception). By convention we put conditions that relate the tables in `ON`, conditions on a single table go in `WHERE`.